# Moving a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

Can anyone link me to an answered question about this as I know it's one of the most common questions asked around here.

It's practically asking how I would use jQuery to slide a div to the left when clicked.

Comment: Wait, you're too lazy to search so you want *us* to search for a duplicate for you? -1

Comment: Ryan, this is not how this site works. You need to show what you've tried and what caused you problems. We will not write the code for you.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Moving+a+div+with+jQuery&oq=Moving+a+div+with+jQuery&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=Moving+a+div+with+jQuery+-+stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#divid').animate({left:'-10px'});

or

http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/
```